Batik won't load svg file
I am trying to load an svg file using batik and display it, but both methods that I have tried have given me different exceptions. I have included both of them in the following code.
public static SVGGraphics2D viewSVG()
{
    File file = findFile();
    DOMImplementation imp = SVGDOMImplementation.getDOMImplementation();
    //SAXSVGDocumentFactory
    SAXSVGDocumentFactory fact = new SAXSVGDocumentFactory(XMLResourceDescriptor.getXMLParserClassName());
    JSVGCanvas canvas = new JSVGCanvas();
    SVGDocument doc = null;
    SVGGraphics2D g = null;
    try {
        doc = fact.createSVGDocument(file.getAbsolutePath());
        g = new SVGGraphics2D(doc);
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        doc = (SVGDocument) imp.createDocument(file.getAbsolutePath(), "svg", null);
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    doc.getRootElement();
    g.setSVGCanvasSize(new Dimension(1000, 1200));
    JFrame frame = new JFrame(doc.getLocalName());
    Element root = doc.getDocumentElement();
    g.getRoot(root);
    canvas.paint(g);
    try {
        Writer out = new FileWriter(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/tst1.svg");
        //g.stream(out, true);
        g.stream(file.getAbsolutePath());
        canvas.paint(g);
        out.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    frame.getContentPane().add(canvas);
    System.out.println(doc.getDocumentElement().getClass());
    System.out.println(doc.getRootElement());
    canvas.setSVGDocument(doc);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
    return g;
}
/*
 * @param find = JFileChooser object to allow user to navigate file explorer
 * @param result = integer indicating if the selection was valid
 * @param@return file = file selected by user
 * uses JFileChooser to allow user to select a file and then return the file if it is valid or null if it is not
 */
public static File findFile()
{
    JFileChooser find = new JFileChooser();
    find.setCurrentDirectory(new File(System.getProperty("user.dir")));
    int result = find.showOpenDialog(find);
    if(JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION == result)
    {
        File file = find.getSelectedFile();
        return file;
    }
    else
    {
        return null;
    }
}


java.io.IOException: Unable to make sense of URL for connection
    at org.apache.batik.util.ParsedURLData.openStreamInternal(ParsedURLData.java:515)
    at org.apache.batik.util.ParsedURLData.openStream(ParsedURLData.java:476)
    at org.apache.batik.util.ParsedURL.openStream(ParsedURL.java:440)
    at org.apache.batik.anim.dom.SAXSVGDocumentFactory.createDocument(SAXSVGDocumentFactory.java:159)
    at org.apache.batik.anim.dom.SAXSVGDocumentFactory.createSVGDocument(SAXSVGDocumentFactory.java:124)
    at calendarmaker.Objects.Pane.viewSVG(Pane.java:118)


java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.apache.batik.dom.GenericElementNS cannot be cast to class org.w3c.dom.svg.SVGSVGElement (org.apache.batik.dom.GenericElementNS and org.w3c.dom.svg.SVGSVGElement are in unnamed module of loader 'app')
    at org.apache.batik.anim.dom.SVGOMDocument.getRootElement(SVGOMDocument.java:234)
    at calendarmaker.Objects.Pane.viewSVG(Pane.java:125)`

Can I get some help please? I don't know what I could be doing wrong as I can view the svg file just fine by clicking on it but I can't seem to load and display it with my code.
I tried to follow different tutorials for loading svg files with batik but none of them worked. I was expecting the svg file to load and then paint it onto a canvas on a JFrame. There might be some stray code in there from when I was trying things, so I apologize in advance.

Needs editing to show the name of the file.getAbsolutePath() as "Unable to make sense of URL` implies you haven't set it correctly.

Try instead doc = fact.createSVGDocument(file.getAbsolutePath().toURI().toString());

Had to get rid of the getAbsolutePath method call but otherwise that worked @g00se

Better not to have it anyway, but surprised you needed to.
